# Windows Phone 8 app changing name of files

Tags: windows-phone-8

My application is receiving a file from OnFileActivated, checking 'args.File[0].Name' I noticed that the name of the file has changed name to simply a number, plus the extension.

How do I receive or get the name of the file as the original name?

Comment: Where do you get the file from? - Maybe it gets cached somehow first and therefore receives a random name?

Comment: I am getting it from another app. CouldSix which is a DropBox app for Windows Phone 8. I am also getting them from the built-in email app, same deal with that one.